# Tweak Nemo so that Delete key doesn't delete irretrievably (NTFS)

Tags: keyboard, ntfs, trash, recovery

OS: Linux Mint 18.3

It appears that on a Linux-type partition pressing the Delete key sends a file or directory to Trash (called "Rubbish Bin" in my system, maybe because I'm in the UK).

But if I press the Delete key in an NTFS partition the file/folder just gets deleted irretrievably (as if using the `rm` command).

Naturally I have numerous backup plans which means nothing disastrous has happened so far.

I also note that any file/directory created in or moved to an NTFS partition always has "root:root" ownership, which may have something to do with it.

If nothing can be done about this, is there any way to just disable the functionality of the Delete key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding in the `fstab` file the option of `uid=your-user-id`.
Use the `id` command to find your user-id number (1000 for the first created user).

The modified line may look like:

```
/dev/sda3 /home/user/shared ntfs defaults,uid=1000,noatime 0 0
```

This will make you the owner and should create a hidden directory `.Trash-1000`
for deleted files to be placed.

After saving the `fstab` file, umount and remount the partition:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda3 && sudo mount -a
```

If you already had a `.Trash-1000` folder which wasn't working, delete it
before re-mounting.

Files deleted from NTFS partitions may be moved to the
folder `/media/username/TheDrive/.Trash-1000`.